# Backup the entire image of Mac book pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I have Mac book pro with OSX-10.7.3, which has to be give back to my company. I bought a new/personal mac book pro and I'd like to copy all the data including  bootcamp images.

Is it possible to take the image/backup of entire disk including bootcamp images??

Do we have to worry about any applications if you take a backup on one mac and restore on other mac ??(for e.g parallel software)

Please suggest the best possible backup/copy method to transfer all the content/data/applications from one mac to other.

Thanks,

Kiran

Answer (score 3):

[Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com) for your OSX partition, and [Winclone](http://twocanoes.com/software.php?software=1) for your Bootcamp partition. Winclone is now commercial software, but I believe you can still download older versions for free elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

[CopyCatX](http://subrosasoft.com/software/copycatx) will do exactly what you want.

You could take a look at Apple's [Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4889), too, for the Mac-to-Mac file transference.

> You can use **Migration Assistant** in OS X Lion to transfer important information, such as user accounts, applications, network and computer settings, and files, from one Mac computer to another via a FireWire cable, ThunderBolt cable, or via an Ethernet or wireless network

Answer (score 1):

Make a Time Machine backup of the OS X partition on the old machine which can be restored on the new mac.  Just insert a virgin USB drive and OS X will offer it itself.  Then insert the drive in the new mac and follow instructions.

For the Boot Camp *partition* enter it and use the backup mechanism included in Windows for that.  Note that the Windows 7 rescue disk wipes the *whole* drive for Windows, not only the Windows partition so don't do that.